# read array with spaces

Tags: arrays, bash

Say I have the file `foo.txt`

```
"The" "quick brown" "fox" "jumps over" "the" "lazy dog."
```

I would like to read these "fields" from the file into an array. However my attempt is failing if the field has a space

```
$ read -a bar < foo.txt

$ echo ${bar[0]}
"The"

$ echo ${bar[1]}
"quick
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the quotation marks?

Comment: Do you want to keep the spaces as field separator or can you replace them and use a suitable IFS?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: FYI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `declare` instead of `eval`:

```
declare -a "bar=( $( < foo.txt ) )"
```

This forces everything in the file to be treated as the right-hand side of the assignment. Using `eval`, the contents of the file can be interpreted as code. For example, if the file contains

```
Some text ); echo "you just erased all your files"; ( true
```

then the following is executed by `eval`:

```
bar=( Some text ); echo "you just erased all your files"; ( true )
```

The parentheses in the file balance the parentheses used outside the command substitution, resulting in the text between them in the file being executed as code rather than being used to populate the array.

Comment: It doesn't work. `echo ${bar[0]}` : `( "The" "quick brown" "fox" "jumps over" "the" "lazy dog." )`. check my solution

Comment: Obviously, I spent more time on the counterexample than the original :) The given file works with "-a", but I am having trouble finding a good example and bad example that both work with the same amount of quoting.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
$ read < foo.txt

$ eval bar=($REPLY)

$ echo ${bar[0]}
The

$ echo ${bar[1]}
quick brown
```

Comment: `declare "bar=( $(< tmp.txt))"` is a little safer; try the eval if the contents of the file are something like `"The" ); echo malicious code; ( true`.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution fails because bash normally uses whitespaces for input field separation `IFS` (and that's also why you get the quotes).

You can use plain `read`, if you prepare your text for processing:

```
IFS='"'
read -a bar < <(sed 's/"\([^"]*\)" */\1"/g' foo.txt)
echo ${bar[1]}

quick brown
```

Note: the sed command transforms the file into this format: `The"quick brown"fox"jumps over"the"lazy dog."`. I use `"` as delimiter as that's definitely not used in the words.

Comment: Only works if your separator is a double-quote

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU awk` and the [FPAT](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) variable:

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=($(awk 'BEGIN { FPAT = "([^ ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }' file.txt))

echo "${array[1]}"
```

Result:

```
"quick brown"
```

Comment: This actually works and is more elegant than other responses. Break (with the field separator) at the newline character and then read the array as whole lines. I've used ```IFS=$'\n' array=( `whatever_command_that_emits_lines_of_text` )``` many times.